# C++ Sin/Cos calculator

Tags: c++, c++11, trigonometry

Without focusing on law of Cosine, my code bellow attempts to solve for the given sides and angles. If there is also a way, how can I use cin >> to retrieve multiple characters, as you can see I ask the user to input either 'A'  or 'S.'

[Here is my code and the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzExx.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char solvefor;
    double A; // I used doubles to have specific answers
    double a;
    double B;
    double b;
    double C;
    double c;

    cout << "What are you trying to solve? <ASA(A) or SSA(S)>";
    cin >> solvefor;
    if (solvefor == 'S')
    {
        cout << "What is the value of b?" << endl;
        cin >> b;
        cout << "What is the angle B?" << endl;
        cin >> B;
        cout << "What is the side c?" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        C = asin((sin(B)/b) * c);
        cout << "Your missing C angle is " << C << endl;
        A = 180 - C - B;
        cout << "Your missing A angle is " << A << endl;
        a = (sin(A) *b) / sin(B);
    } else {
        return 0;       //I will work on law of cosine later
    } 
}
```

I would receive the answers in radians rather than degrees, any help?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: sin and cos functions use radians grade

Comment: not clear what you are asking about the character input, the way it is now is fine

Comment: note to editor: I have rolled back - the code in the question is properly posted already. Questions should preferably not contain screenshots embedded, but providing a link is alright given that the code is already posted

Comment: Please stop editing a screenshot of code into the question guys...

Answer (score 1):

**How to convert value from degree to radian**

```
#define PI 3.14159265
C_in_radian = C * (PI / 180.0); // here C is in degree
```

Modify your code as follows.

```
C = asin((sin(B)/b) * c);
double C_raidan = C * (PI / 180.0);
cout << "Your missing C angle is " << C_raidan << endl;
A = 180 - C - B;
double A_radian = A * (PI / 180.0);
cout << "Your missing A angle is " << A_radian << endl;
```

Output:

```
What are you trying to solve? <ASA(A) or SSA(S)> S
What is the value of b?
8
What is the angle B?
31
What is the side c?
13
Your missing C angle is -0.0125009
Your missing A angle is 2.61304
```

Please go through this - [Converting Radians to Degrees and vice-versa](https://math.usask.ca/emr/examples/rmoa_eg1.html).

If you want to know how `asin` or `sin` works in C++, see [asin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/asin/) and [sin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/).

**Edit**

According to @G.Sliepen suggestions, we should use `M_PI` from `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`.

We just need to use:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C++  
#include <cmath>
```

OR

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES // for C  
#include <math.h>
```

Then we can use:

```
double C_raidan = C * (M_PI / 180.0); // M_PI is a math constant
```

See [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6.aspx).

Comment: Please do **not** `#define PI` yourself. Most of the times I've seen people do this, they do it wrong. Either use the macro `M_PI` from `<cmath>`, or if that is not available on your platform, do something like `static const double PI = 4 * atan(1);`